# For what complex $c$ does the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-c}$ have a Laurent expansion on the annulus $A=\{z : 1<|z|<2\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

"For what complex numbers $c$ does the function $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-c}$ have a Laurent expansion on the annulus $A=\{z : 1<|z|<2\}$? Determine this expansion explicitly."

Since $f(z)$ has a singularity at $z=c$, $\ f(z)$ is holomorphic on the domains: $|z|<c$ and $c<|z|<\infty$, which implies $c=1$ and $c=2$, right?

So would the solution be:
$\frac{1}{z-1}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{z^{n+1}} \ (1<|z|)$,$\ $
$\frac{1}{z-2}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{-z^n}{2^{n+1}} \ (|z|<2)$?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Dont you think $c=i$, $c=-2$ would also be fine? What about $c=0$ or $c=42$?

Comment: Since $f(z)$ needs to be holomorphic in the annulus to have a Laurent series there, we have $|c| \leq 1$ and $|c| \geq 2$, so yes. So if $|c| \leq 1$, then $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{c^n}{z^{n+1}} \ (|c|<|z|)$, and if $|c| \geq 2$|, then  $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{-z^n}{c^{n+1}} \ (|z|<|c|)$?

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is analytic on $A$, you must have either $|c| \le 1$ or
$|c| \ge 2$.

In the first case, if $z \in A$, then $|z| > |c|$. Write $f(z) = {1 \over z} {1 \over 1-{c \over z}}$.

In the second case, if $z \in A$, then $|z| < |c|$. Write $f(z) = -{1 \over c} {1 \over 1-{z \over c}}$.